# get files depend on user enter date

Tags: c#

my question is how to get file from direction depend on creation time.The user enter date in text box after click on a button the result will display on list box. my code is bellow but I don't get the file depend on exact date.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp_sat");
    FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.MSG");
    DateTime dt;

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        dt = File.GetCreationTime(file.ToString());
        if (TextBox1.Text.Equals(dt.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm"))) 
            ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: So... what is the question here?

Comment: So you want to get a list of files created aon a specified date and time? If so, what is the output of your code? What is failing there?

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp_sat");
FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.MSG");
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text.Equals(file.CreationTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

- You should use `HH` for hours (I believe you want 24-hour pattern).
- `FileInfo` already has `CreationTime`
  property.

Comment: @LooLy Can you show what do you enter in textbox? Can you show `dir` output?

Comment: I entered (201405080300) in the textbox... And no output displayed in the listbox

Comment: @LooLy Are you sure you have files created between 2014.05.08 03:00~04:00? Another question: do you have any items in `files` array?

Comment: yes, I'm sure...I think the problem is inside if statement because when I remove it I get all the data inside that file

Comment: @LooLy My prev comment is wrong. It should be file created between 2014.05.08 03:00~03:01.

Comment: @LooLy Again, can you make `dir`? I don't know your culture, so you have to adjust accordingly: `dir | findstr "08/05/2014  03`

Comment: @LooLy I mean run `dir` in command line and copy output here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change how you get dt to

```
dt = file.CreationTime;
```